# Should I use a separate model for user address?

Tags: php, database, model-view-controller, model

I have a registration form where the user enters customer information and invoice/delivery address information. A customer/user can have several delivery addresses and one invoice address.

I have a database table with customer information (name, username, phone and email) and a database table with addresses.

I have a model where I insert and select customer info (example code below). Should I create a new model for the addresses that are in another table or can I use the customer model?

Read that a new model should not be created per table because there is a relationship between customer and address but instead after business object.

Does this mean that I should also use my customer class to manage addresses even though they are in a different table?

/Model/Customer.php

```
class Customer
{
public function getCustomer($username)
    {
        $query = 'SELECT * FROM customer where username = ?';
        $paramType = 's';
        $paramValue = array(
            $username
        );
        $customerRecord = $this->ds->select($query, $paramType, $paramValue);
        return $customerRecord;
    }
}
```

Comment: Does your code ever have to deal with addresses only (without the need to fetch the customer as well)?

Comment: @El_Vanja No. I save the addresses when the user register and get the users addresses  when they login. I need to get the addresses through the user.

Comment: Well, in that case they might not warrant a model of their own. You could design them as DTOs instead.

Answer (score 0):

> A customer/user can have several delivery addresses and one invoice address.

Looking at it like this, it makes me think you should have a *delivery_addresses* table to store all of the customer **delivery addresses** and then you could either store the invoice address as columns in the users table or you could create another table called *invoice_addresses* and store them there.

> Does this mean that I should also use my customer class to manage addresses even though they are in a different table?

You could create a method in your Customer class that returns the addresses. Something like this:

```
$customerDeliveryAddresses = Customer::find(1)->deliveryAddresses()->get();
```

Have you looked into [Eloquent](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent)? It seems that you're writing out raw SQL when you could use a really nice ORM library like Eloquent to do all the heavy lifting for you.